# Cycle through and pull information from array in Twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig, twig-extension

I currently have an array full of pre-populated form fields:

```
$fields = array('title','first_name')

$info = array(
    'title' => 'Mr',
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Smith'
)
```

As you can see this particular fields array only contains the title and first name.

My objective is to cycle through the fields array and see if I have any information in my `$info` array to pre-populate the field with.

Something like:

```
foreach (fields as field) {
    if (field  is in $info array) {
        echo the_field_value;
    }
}
```

But obviously in Twig, currently I have something like:

```
{% for key, field in context.contenttype.fields %}
    {% if key in context.content|keys %} << is array
        {{ key.value }}<< get the value of the field
    {%  endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example dump what you need:

```
{%  set fields = ['title','first_name'] %}

{% set info = { 'title': 'Mr', 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith' } %}


{% for key in fields %}
    {% if key in info|keys %}
        {{ info[key] }}
    {%  endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Result:

> Mr John

Here the working solutions: http://twigfiddle.com/i3w2j3

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I was unaware if the info[key] feature.